# Multi StringReplace in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

How can I replace yes to 1 and no to 0?
**Example: (NOT WORKING!)**

```
str_replace("yes","1",$data,"no","0",$data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace("yes", "1", str_replace("no", "0", $data));
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [str_replace()](http://de.php.net/str_replace) supports array arguments:

```
var_dump(
  str_replace(array('yes', 'no'), array('1', '0'), $data)
);
```

[strtr()](http://de.php.net/strtr) supports an replacement array:

```
var_dump(
  strtr($data, array('yes' => 1, 'no' => 0))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = str_replace("yes","1",$data);
$data = str_replace("no","0",$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'This is yes, this is no';
$str = preg_replace(array('/yes/i', '/no/i'), array('1', '0'), $str);

echo $str; // This is 1, this is 0
```